# Notation for the index of an element of a disjoint union

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, notation

Suppose I have a set $I$ and an $I$-indexed family of sets $\{A_i\}$. I can write the disjoint union (aka coproduct) as
$$
\sum_{i\in I} A_i.
$$
An element of this set is a pair $(i,a)$ with $i\in I$ and $a\in A_i$.

My question is, is there an established / typical notation for getting the first element of this pair? If it was an element $(i,j)$ of $I\times J$, then I would write $\pi_0$, e.g. $\pi_0((i,j)) = i$, but using $\pi_0$ looks a bit weird for the disjoint union, because the projection maps are part of the definition of the product, not the sum.

Answer (score 1):

$\pi_0$ is a very reasonable notation to use here (though you'll have to specify your meaning regardless.) The construction $\sum_{i\in I} A_i$ is the *dependent sum* of the $I$-indexed family, and in that context $I\times J=\sum_{i\in I} J$ is simply the dependent sum of a *constant* family.

Answer (score 1):

There is no established notation for this map. If you want to use a notation in a paper / lecture, you will have to explain it.